# How many files in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, setup

I am new to Magento. According to other sites, Magento seems to be the best open source store software. Does anyone know how much files are in the latest Magento?

My hosting provider has a limit of 20000 inodes, so I need to know if I need to upgrade my plan or not.

Comment: You can use [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9157162/6837445) to calculate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

out of my head, magento can easily reach 13.000 files/folders. each product image creates multiple files for caching purposes. theres also other caches. I suggets you find yourself a hosting company who knows a thing or 2 about hosting magento webshops becouse it really needs some good hosting to be able to deliver good performance. About the 20k inodes, youll reach it pretty quickly is my guess, depends on the shop ofcourse.

My answer, go look for a magento specialized hosting company to get the maximum performance out of your webshop.

Comment: My web store is very small, so I guess I will be fine. Thanks for answering! I won't be able to use FTP then...

Comment: your call, if it's tiny i think youll be fine but watch your growth. If youre experiencing performance problems get yourself some other hosting package. the shared hosting mostly isn't the best choice becouse magento is a "big and heavy" cms.

Comment: @Joe Why can't you use FTP?

Comment: I'm a little curious about that one too :P

Comment: Magento 1.9.2.0 clocks in at 14,391 Files, 5,377 Folders and 109MB and that's before you add themes, modules and all your image libraries.

Comment: @travisw Too much files, it would take too long. Probably an hour...

Comment: @FiascoLabs Thanks! How did you know that?

Comment: @Joe - Just extracted a downloaded copy of the gzip installer and did a file/directory count and noted the total file size. Don't know how many tables we're up to, didn't check that as I don't want nightmares.

Comment: @travisw - You are best off copying the full installer archive itself to your website and extracting via the SSH command shell. SFTP exponentially slows down handling all the directory recursion and file creation on something this size and file system complexity, leading to failed uploads, missing files, corrupted files and all the other headaches you DO NOT NEED in addition to the issues Magento already throws your way. It's one of the reasons that Magento Connect upgrades fail so miserably as well. TAR archives were made to handle this very problem.

Comment: @FiascoLabs My laptop just crashes when I try to unzip it :D

Answer (score 1):

use `find your_magento_dir -type f | wc -l`

seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9157138/recursively-counting-files-in-a-linux-directory)